# Writing some data to a specific area within a file in PHP

Tags: php, fopen

I'm experimenting with `fopen` for the first time and was wondering if it was possible to search for a particular section within a file before adding or replacing that content with data?

Ideally, I'd like to:

1. Use `fopen` to get the file
2. Search for a comment called `<!-- test -->`
3. Replace that comment with new data.

This possible? (for the record - Appending data to the end of the file or adding new data to a specific line number would not work for what I'm working on as the file is constantly changing).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the entire file in then use something str_replace to make the change, you should be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
// make sure radio is set
if( isset($_POST['enableSocialIcons']) )
{
  // Open file for read and string modification 
  $file = "/test"; 
  $fh = fopen($file, 'r+'); 
  $contents = fread($fh, filesize($file)); 
  $new_contents = str_replace("hello world", "hello", $contents); 
  fclose($fh); 

  // Open file to write 
  $fh = fopen($file, 'r+'); 
  fwrite($fh, $new_contents); 
  fclose($fh); 
}
?>
```

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#81325

**EDIT:** To see what exactly is getting sent by your form do this at the top of the PHP file you're posting to:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

exit;

?>
```

Comment: Still having an issue if you have time to help:


I'm trying to get a bit of logic working based on whether the value of a radio button is checked as yes or no. If it's yes then I want to replace the content using fopen with some data that was inputted into an input field. If it's no then I want to replace the content with nothing. Here's my code: (there's no errors at all. It just doesn't seem to like my radio buttons. (I got it working fine testing if an input field was empty or not btw.)

http://pastebin.com/fQN608A7
I just pasted the areas related to my issue so not all the file is there).

Comment: for the record, I tested $enableSocialIcons and it does return yes or no successfully when I try to echo it after form submission

Comment: If the radio button is no: 

Array
(
    [field] => 
    [enableSocialIcons] => yes
    [twitter] => 
)

if the radio button is yes:

Array
(
    [field] => 
    [enableSocialIcons] => yes
    [twitter] =>
)

The str_replace works fine and adds my twitter link in fine. But my problem is that when I select no, it's not doing what I want. It's acting as if I've selected yes. From what I understand, It *should* be doing a str_replace on that comment to make it completely blank. sorry about the bad formatting, it does it automatically on comments.